# Joomla homepage and global configuration showing 404 error, how do I fix it?

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-404

When I go to the homepage url of my `joomla` site a `404 error` shows up that simply says `404 Not Found`.  I have the home page set as the default in the menus item manager.  Are there any other ways to fix this?  Also, I am getting a `404 error` when I go to the global configuration page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we have the same problem. I think your joomla site may have been hacked as well, and  the fix for this is easy. You just basically need to delete files. Here's a reference to the problem  http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=428&t=786545.